# Array as an attribute in a java class?

Tags: java, arrays, red-black-tree

I have an assignment which consists of several small tasks:

1. I have to initilize an array and fill it with a 200/400/800 values (each amount - once).
2. I have to take the array values and put it in a red black tree, with certain conditions that are translated to methods.
3. Some more tasks.

I could do it all in the main class, however it seems to me I would be better off start a new **class - handleArray**.

If I start a class such as:

```
public class handlyArray{
    protected int [] arr = new int[];
}
```

But if I do that, should I write a "get" and "set" functions to get the array's length?

The problem is that when I make this an error pops up - "Array initilizer expected".

Additional functions I have in the class:

```
public void fillArray(handleArray arr, int k){
        Random rand=new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i <k ; i++) {
            int value = rand.nextInt(1024);
            arr[i]=value;
        }
    }
```

- **A function that creates Nodes for the redblackTree and inserts them to the tree**

Any suggestions for how to build it?
**Can I build the class with no attributes at all?**

Thanks!

Comment: When you initialize an array, you have to specify the size of the array. `new int[];` is not valid. It must be something like `new int[100];`, or you must explicitly specify values: `new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };`. Note that an array's size is fixed once created (arrays cannot be resized).

Comment: I understand. However what do I do if I have three diffrent sizes I need?

Comment: You could initialise the array in your class's constructor, and pass the length in as a constructor parameter.

Comment: "a new class - handleArray" - please read the Java code conventions, the class should be named `HandleArray` at least. That said, from a design point of view that name isn't that good and since you're thinking about better design (that's how I understand your question) you should think of a more appropriate name as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm wary of this being homework so I'll give you an overview and let you do the specifics.

Yes you can build a getter and setter in your new class, something like:

```
public int[] getArray() {
    return arr;
}

public void setArray(int[] arr) {
    this.arr = arr; //
}
```

As for getting the length, you don't *need* a method for it as you can just call the above getter and ask it for the length, e.g.

```
int arrayLength = handlyArray.getArray().length;
```

Finally yes you need to set up your array first, if you pass in an initialized array to the setter that will do fine, e.g.

```
handlyArray.setArray(new int[] {200, 400, 800});
```

Good luck, feel free to ask if you require further explanation.

Comment: It is homework :-) I wrote it down - an assignment. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Alan I was simply acknowledging that. If you agree with any of the answers given, please tick the one you accept as correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can inisialize the array inside the method like this :

```
public void fillArray(handlyArray arr, int k) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    arr.arr = new int[k];//<<---------------------Initialize the array
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        int value = rand.nextInt(1024);
        arr.arr[i] = value;// Note to fill the array you have to use arr.arr not just arr
    }
}
```

and the handlyArray should be like this :

```
public class handlyArray {
    protected int[] arr;//<<---------------------Just declare the array
}
```

to use `fillArray` method you can use :

```
a.fillArray(new handlyArray(), length);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. I would just do a static method somewhere:

```
public static int[] randomArray(int size){
    Random rand=new Random();
    int[] arr = new int[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size ; i++) {
        int value = rand.nextInt(1024);
        arr[i]=value;
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Now, as for the red/black tree, I believe that a TreeSet is implemented with a red/black tree.

Comment: You would do everything in the main method and that's it?

Comment: @Alan the initialization of a random array, yes, definitely.

Answer (score 0):

You can't set an arrays length. The length of an array has to be set during initialization. You can pass the length of the array in the constructor of your class:

```
public class HandleArray {

  protected int [] arr;

  public HandleArray(int length) {
    arr  = new int[length];
  }
}
```